# Relative position with background image

Tags: css, position

I have a div I would like which I have placed at 25% from the top. However, the 25% are computed with respect to the size of the background image and not with respect to the size of the visible screen. How can this be fixed?

#### Update: now the top margin works, but not the left one :(

Any clue?

```
body {
    background: #eeeeee url('pix/bg-noether-2.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    align: center;
} 

#container {
    background-color: #ffffe4;
    position: absolute;
    width: 776px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 25%;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any markup/css your trying that you could show us?

Comment: make sure it's not relative to anotehr div and use `position:absolute;top:25%;`

Answer (score 2):

1) use absolute positioning:

```
#myDiv { position: absolute; top: 25%; }
```

2) make sure your div is not within another positioned element (if you're not sure of this, just put it just inside the `<body>` tag, nothing else)

Answer (score 1):

use css property:

```
div#myDiv {
position:absolute;
top: 25%;
}
```

on the dive that you want placed 25% from top of visible screen.

Comment: There's no reason to have "div" before #myDiv - there should only be one element per page with the same ID, so - specifying what type of element it is is overkill (especially if the id has "Div" in it).

Comment: I agree. I do this out of habbit and would obviously not name the element myDiv. I just did this for demo purposes only.

Comment: No matter what the name of the ID - also selecting the element with the ID is overkill in any way.

Answer (score 0):

if you use relative position then the percentage will be calculated from the parent element.

if you use absolute position the percentage will be calculated from the size of the screen.

So try to using position absolute instead of relative.

edited answer for comment, just add extra div with id wrapper and change postitions, see example below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body { 
background: #eeeeee url('pix/bg-noether-2.jpg') no-repeat center top;  
background-attachment: fixed; 
overflow: hidden; 
text-align: center; 
}
#wrapper {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
} 
#container { 
background-color: #ffffe4; 
position: relative; 
margin:0 auto;
width: 776px; 
height: 400px; 
top: 25%; 
text-align: center; 
overflow: auto; 
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        bla bla bla
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The top margin works, but on the left: nada. The div sticks to the left margin. The code is here under. Any clue?

body {
        background: #eeeeee url('pix/bg-noether-2.jpg') no-repeat center top;
        background-size: auto 100%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        overflow: hidden;
        align: center;
}

#container {
         background-color: #ffffe4;
         position: absolute;
         width: 776px;
         height: 400px;
         top: 25%;
         margin-left: auto;
         text-align: center;
         overflow: auto;
}